# Regex in validation.xml

Tags: xml, regex, jsp

how would I add a line for a regex check to make sure only A letter of the alphabet.. A-Z is entered in this form field?

```
<field property="code" depends="required,maxlength">
        <msg name="required" key="Code is required." resource="false" />
        <msg name="maxlength" key="Code has a max length of {0}" resource="false" />
        <arg name="maxlength" key="${var:maxlength}" resource="false" />
        <var>
           <var-name>maxlength</var-name>
           <var-value>1</var-value>
        </var>
     </field>
  </form>
```

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is `[A-Z]+` assuming your question is accurate

Comment: Just a check to make sure they only put in a letter of the alphabet in that field.  It only accept 1 character

Comment: Then just the `[A-Z]` is needed - no +